# What metal (or alloy) is Abraham Setrakian's sword made from?

Tags: urban-fantasy, the-strain

I've been binge watching the FX show "The Strain". In the show, there is a character, Abraham Setrakian, that has a sword-cane made to kill the vampires.

[image: =Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I was sitting here wondering how this was even possible. Silver, (As far as I know, I don't know much about chemistry.) is a very weak metal and wouldn't function as anything more than a decorative piece. However, we see the sword cut all the way through the neck to take off heads without leaving any sort of damage or noticeable marks on the blade.

What is the sword made of? Is it an alloy of silver and another metal? Do we have any legitimate information on what this sword is made of? And, would silver function as a blade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Setrakian (in the [source novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strain)), his sword-cane is made of silver *and only silver*. This is one of a number of silver weapons we see in the books including nails, daggers, bullets and bolts. Several are described as being made from "pure" silver and there's no suggestion that they've been adulterated or alloyed with other metals for hardness.

> “I say, ‘Strigoi, my sword sings of silver.’” Setrakian winced again, uncomfortable saying this now. “Sounds better in the old language.”
>   Nora saw that this old vampire killer was essentially a modest man. **“Silver,” she said.**
>   **“Only silver,”** he said. “Renowned throughout the ages for its antiseptic and germicidal properties. You can cut them with steel or shoot them with lead, but only silver really hurts them.”

Interestingly, the cane and handle are described as being ***"encrusted"*** 
 with silver, implying that the substrate is another, harder substance. Note that this doesn't refer to the sword contained within.

> He pushed the three of them away, waving off his bodyguards as well, standing erect despite the ache. His detail remained below while **he used his silver-encrusted walking stick** to shoo the girls up the curling flights of blue-veined white marble to the penthouse.

---

As to whether *pure* silver would actually be a viable metal from which to make a sword in real life, the answer is a solid nope. Even using modern cold-forging techniques and compression-folding the metal into multilayered sheets would still result in a blade that was brittle, tarnished easily, would be fabulously hard to sharpen and could be chopped through (with a normal steel blade) like it was made of plywood.

Comment: Great answer! I actually read the novels awhile ago when they first came out. I completely forgot about that though.

Comment: @E.Huckabee - Silver weapons are very tropey and kind of easy to miss. There's a few scenes where they talk about weapons that are coated in silver (a stake that Setrakian makes, for example) that seem similarly effective.